# Why $r^{(p+1)/2} = -r \pmod{p}$.

Tags: number-theory

> If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, prove that $−r$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$.
>
> If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, prove that $−r$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

The (start of the ) Proof: Recall that the order of an element a
k modulo n is precisely
ordn(a)/gcd(k,ordn(a)).
Thus, the order of −r is precisely p − 1/gcd((p + 1)/2, p − 1). Thus we need
to determine gcd((p + 1)/2, p − 1).

it seems from the answer that r^(p+1)/2 = -r mod p.

Why?

Comment: **Please** ...go to the FAQ section for directions to use LaTeX in this site to properly write mathematics...

Comment: And what in the world is $\,r\,$, anyway?!

Comment: just an integer

Comment: Why  r^(p+1)/2 = -r mod p.?

Comment: Well @user1932595, then write that $\,r\,$ is just an integer!

Comment: TMM, no...I want explantion about this proof..

Comment: If $r$ is a primitive root, then see the linked question for answers. If $r$ is just some integer, this question does not make any sense.

Comment: I think that what the OP tried to ask, in a rather sloppy way, is: prove that if $\,r\,$ is a primitive root of unity modulo $\,p=3\pmod 4\,$ , then ....etc. Otherwise this just makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to show that $\,r\in\Bbb Z\;,\;p=3\pmod 4\implies r^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=-r\pmod p\,$ , then the claim is false:

$$2^{\frac{7+1}{2}}=2^4=16=2\pmod 7\neq-2=5\pmod 7$$